# Ошибка при установке numpy и pillow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, pillow

```
pip install numpy pillow              
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.26.2.tar.gz (15.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [383 lines of output]
      Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
        Using cached ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'    
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [360 lines of output]
        C:\Users\ilyxa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nac2lace\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not support describe output
          warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
        C:\Users\ilyxa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nac2lace\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)
          warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
          Generator
     
            Visual Studio 17 2022
     
          could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
     
     
     
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
          Generator
     
            Visual Studio 16 2019
     
          could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
     
     
     
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
          Generator
     
            Visual Studio 15 2017
     
          could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
     
     
     
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
          Running
     
           'nmake' '-?'
     
          failed with:
     
           no such file or directory
     
     
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
          Running
     
           'nmake' '-?'
     
          failed with:
     
           no such file or directory
     
     
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     
     
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Trying 'NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)' generator
        --------------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ----------------------
        -----------------
        ------------
        -------
        --
        Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
        CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
          Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
          CMake.
     
          Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
          CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
     
     
        CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
          Running
     
           'nmake' '-?'
     
          failed with:
     
           no such file or directory
     
     
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        --
        -------
        ------------
        -----------------
        ----------------------
        ---------------------------
        --------------------------------
        -- Trying 'NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)' generator - failure
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
                        ********************************************************************************
                        scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.
     
                        Building windows wheels for Python 3.10 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.
        Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":
     
          https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
     
        Or with "Visual Studio 2019":
     
            https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
     
        Or with "Visual Studio 2022":
     
            https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
     
                        ********************************************************************************
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Операционная система: Windows 10 Pro x64 на AMD
Python 3.10.11
Пишу код в VS Code'е

UPD тут советовали `pip install numpy --no-cache-dir` использовать, однако вылазит новая ошибка:

```
pip install numpy --no-cache-dir
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.26.2.tar.gz (15.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.7/15.7 MB 72.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [36 lines of output]
      Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
        Using cached ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [13 lines of output]
        C:\Users\ilyxa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnfiyi1o\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not support describe output
          warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
        C:\Users\ilyxa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnfiyi1o\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)
          warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\ilyxa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnfiyi1o\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
            cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\ilyxa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnfiyi1o\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
            self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\ilyxa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnfiyi1o\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
            raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
     
        Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Ну вообще numpy на Python 3.10 на windows (хоть 32-битную, хоть 64-битную) должен без проблем ставиться. Пробуйте без кэша ставить, может он тогда whl скачает: `pip install numpy --no-cache-dir`

Comment: А так оно вроде говорит "хочу Visual Studio 2022, если нет, то ладно, можно более старую - 2019, 2017, но я чёт никакую найти не могу".

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @CrazyElf Я может чего не понимаю но зачем и для чего ему нужно vs 20xx качать, ну и к тому-же я пользуюсь VScode

Comment: @ИльяМалютин с отключенным кэшем в итоге пробовали устанавливать?

Comment: @insolor К сожалению нет

Comment: @ИльяМалютин "к сожалению нет" - не пробовали?

Comment: @insolor пробовал, однако выводит практически тоже самое

Comment: Добавьте версию операционной системы и версию python (вместе с "битностью" в вопрос)

Comment: А если сделать радикально? `pip install --only-binary :all: numpy`

Comment: @andreymal выводит вот такую ошибку: 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

Comment: @ИльяМалютин `VS` (вернее, её `SDK`) нужна для того, чтобы скомпилировать пакеты под нужную вам платформу. `Numpy` вообще проблемный пакет, он просто так не всегда ставится, поэтому бывает проще его в составе `Anaconda` поставить, например, а не через `pip`.

Comment: @CrazyElf numpy и pillow оба есть в скомпилированном виде, значит должны ставиться без проблем

Comment: @andreymal Видимо, не под всякую архитектуру есть. Я правда давно не следил, но пару лет назад приходилось компилировать ещё. Я поэтому обычно через `conda` ставлю.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну под x64 очевидно есть

Comment: По обновлённой ошибке - опять же не может `cmake` найти. Поставьте уже `VS SDK` и не мучайтесь, пригодится.

Comment: @CrazyElf под популярные платформы и актуальные версии python whl на pypi есть: https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files . Почему в данном случае их не находит - загадка.

Comment: @insolor Может сам питон установлен x32? ))  Или такого варианта уже не бывает для современных версий? )

Comment: @CrazyElf ну вы по ссылке ходили же?) Там и x64 и x32 версии есть

Comment: @insolor Тогда у меня больше нет идей )